# Handle a string from a Dll in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get a value from a string, this string comes from a Dll

```
PhysiologicParametersDll.PhysiologicParametersDll dll = new PhysiologicParametersDll.PhysiologicParametersDll();

        dll.Initialize(myProcessedMethod, 15000, checkBlood.Checked, checkHeart.Checked, checkOxy.Checked);
```

The dll will return values to a string

```
 private void myProcessedMethod(string message)
    {

        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(message);
        }));
```

And i will recive multiple values like this in textbox while dll is active

> BP;141-84;18/03/2017 18:22:06
>
> SPO2;84;18/03/2017 18:22:07
>
> HR;101;18/03/2017 18:22:08

I will use 3 diferents textbox for BP value SPO2 value and HR value

I need to only show the last value from all of this parameteres in different textboxs and only can run 1 dll that give me all of this values at the same time.

What i want to put in each text box is the value between the two ; ;

Exemple:
BP     141-84
SPO2   84
HR     101

And everytime the dll give me new values i want to replace the old ones.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please explain more what you want to put in the each textbox.

Comment: What i want to put in each text box is the value between the two ; ;                                 Example:    BP.       141-84   // SPO2   84 // HR   101;    and everytime the dll give me new values i want to replace the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could do something like this:

```
private void myProcessedMethod(string message)
{
    var values = message.Split(';');
    // Decide in which textbox to display the value.
    var textBox = values[0] == "BP" ? richTextBox1 : values[0] == "SPO2" ? richTextBox2 : richTextBox3;

    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        textBox.Text = values[1];
    }));
}
```

Maybe you don't need to use reach text box, but regular text box. I don't have a complete context.

Comment: i dont rly need to use a reach text box im just using it now to handle all of this values

Comment: tank you i solve my problem using the split and var values.